# Does linux init process run in kernel or user mode?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, gnu

I am trying to learn linux kernel, in TLDP the linux kernel 2.0 book. Is init a process or kernel thread i don't know the exact difference though. And does it run in physicial or virtual memory space? Kernel related stuff usually use physicial memory space but if it is a process thing could change.

Can anyone share their knowledge/experience on that.

Comment: Not a good place to ask such question.

Comment: I think it is in user mode. 'init' is a process.

Comment: Jord the stackexchange unix area was down. So i thought it wouldn't be that inapproipriate to ask.

Comment: Xiaoge Su, but it is the process of kernel itself that is what confused me. But on the another hand the other processes fork from init process at the beginning. But i don't know during forking kernel can change the mode of a process or access attributes uid gid of the process. Deamn i am confused

Comment: I am learning the kernel by reading multiple books simultenously and yes I read lots about the init process though obviously i missed that Jim you don't need to be harsh. People always ask the asked before questions on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

Init is a user process like any other processes, so it is using virtual memory. The only thing that is special about init is that it is one of the two processes that the kernel started initially. When init is started by the kernel, it goes into user mode. When init calls system call fork(), it traps into the kernel mode, and the kernel does a bunch of things to create the new process, and the new process will be scheduled in the future. When the fork() returns, the original process is back to user mode.

Btw, even kernel is also using virtual memory, the mapping of kernel memory addresses are shared among processes.

Comment: wow thank you! Enlightened me more than i asked for!

Comment: hi, what's the other process started by kernel?